# Illegal Call of Nonstatic Member Function if Multiple Inheriting Templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

I have a Host with 2 policies, each of which with a `print` function.
If I call `Policy::print()`, there's no problem, but if I call `OtherPolicy::print()` then I get an error.

```
Error   C2352    'OtherPolicy<T,Host<T,SubPolicy,OtherPolicy>>::printer': illegal call of non-static member function
        with
        [
            T=uint32_t
        ]   Scratch D:\tmp\ScratchCpp\Scratch\Scratch\HostPolicy.h  63
```

```
#include <iostream>

template<
    typename T,
    class Host
>
class Policy {
public:
    virtual void printer()
    {
        std::cout << "base policy" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<
    typename T,
    class Host
>
class SubPolicy : Policy<T, Host> {
public:
    void printer() override
    {
        auto host = static_cast<Host&>(*this);
        std::cout << "sub policy" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<
    typename T,
    class Host
>
class OtherPolicy {
public:
    void printer()
    {
        auto host = static_cast<Host&>(*this);
        std::cout << "other policy" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<
    typename T,
    template<typename, class> class A,
    template<typename, class> class B
>
class Host :
    public A<T, Host<T, A, B>>,
    public B<T, Host<T, Policy, B>> {
public:
    void printer()
    {
        std::cout << "host" << std::endl;
        A<T, Host>::printer();
        B<T, Host>::printer(); // comment out this line to compile successfully
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Host<uint32_t, SubPolicy, OtherPolicy> host;
    host.printer();
}
```

Would someone be so kind as to explain what's going on and how to do this properly?

Comment: If you have several such calls in your code then I'd suggest a readability typedef, e.g. `using ParentB = B<T, Host<T, Policy, B>>;` in the private section, and then the call would be `ParentB::printer();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second base class for `Host` is of type `B<T, Host<T, Policy, B>>`, *not* `B<T, Host>`.  This results in the error, because `B<T, Host>` is not a base class of `Host`.

The fix is to properly name the type of the base class:

```
B<T, Host<T, Policy, B>>::printer();
```

Comment: Interesting!  Why do I need to fully declare the parameters for `Host` for `B` but not for `A`?

Comment: @calben When you specify `Host` in `A<T, Host>` from within the `Host` class declaration, it is referring to the class being declared (just like you can declare constructors with just `Host` without repeating the types).  This will use the same template parameters as if you specified `Host<T, A, B>`.  Since the base class `B` uses a different class for the second template parameter of `Host`, you need to specify them when you access the class.  Otherwise you end up with `B<T, Host<T, A, B>>`.